# Prolog Split list

Tags: list, prolog

I need to create a `split/4` function in Prolog and I am pretty sure I am close, however there is an error I can not see. The program will take a list, a key, and two lists for output (small and big). If the element in the list is smaller than key put it in small, else put it in big.

So what I have now is:

```
split([H|T], Key, [H|ST], Big) :- H < Key, split(T, Key, ST, Big).
split([H|T], Key, Small, [H|BT]) :- H >= Key, split(T, Key, Small, BT).
```

I can assume that the list and key are instantiated. If someone can point out my error that would be great! I'd like to understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is a base case. Currently your predicate isn't able to do anything when the input list is empty, which eventually happens for any input after all items of the list have been processed.

```
split([], _, [], []).
```

Simply add this rule and it will work as expected.

Comment: wow, I can not believe it was something so simple that I missed! Thanks!